# Zend pagination items numbers in loop

Tags: zend-framework, pagination

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
       <?php foreach($this->paginator as $client): ?>
       <?php $i++ ;?>

<tr>
     <td><?=$i?></td>
     <td class="hidden-phone"><?=$client['cmp_name']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

If I click second page 2 or 3 etc. I see items numbers from 1, I try multiply $i variable by page number, but I can't get page number in view :

```
$page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
```

This method work only in controller, maybe are methods to display item numbers in 2,3,4 page not from 1 but from next values 5,6,7 ?

Comment: Paginator has metod `getCurrentPageNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use limit to get data from your DB table ?
it must to show 0-5, than 5-10, ...etc